# How much disk space needed for Bitcoin SV testnet node implementation?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet, bitcoin-sv

I want to create Bitcoin SV node but not sure how much disk space it needed.

please someone answer me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the actoal SV-testnet blockchain size. But, if see to mainnet - 
because of this is relative fresh fork of Bitcoin, blockchain size is close to Bitcoin's one, i.e. 200G.
Please, be careful:

- BitcoinSV runs as a daemon on a Linux only, and there is not exists a GUI wallet.
- It uses directory $HOME/.bitcoin to hold
  blockchain and wallet.dat. As result, if you use Bitcoin on same
  Linux server/account, then BitcoinSV will hurt your Bitcoins wallet.dat and
  blockchain. I recommend backup or rename your .bitcoin before run SV.
- Config command "zapwallettxes" does not work correctly. In my case,
  it clears balance from wallet.dat, I restored it from backup.

Comment: i changed .bitcoin directory but i'm not able to get console. how can i generate address and check balance in it and do transaction etc.
please reply

Comment: there must be program "bitcoin-cli". Run it, for example: "bitcoin-cli getbalance" or "bitcoin-cli help". Of course, it works, only whenever daemon is running.

Comment: I really appreciate for your quick and valuable response @olegarch .
Thank you so muuch

Comment: i created node but facing one issue, i generated address in node its giving me bitcoincash:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx address format. how can i get some test coin or i try to get some coin from https://bitcoincloud.net/faucet/ it's giving me invalid address error
what would be solution for this ?
I'll be very thankful to you please reply

Comment: i do not have ideas about SV and it's testnet. However, for experiments, I can recommend you to use Emercoin, and I can provide you test coins for free. I am CTO of Emercoin, and can assist with this crypto much more. See about our project: https://emercoin.com

Comment: I face another problem as i process ahead, how can i mine test coin in my node ?
Also can;t create wallet in my test node ?
please reply

Comment: I can suggest for Emercoin only. I With Emercoin, you can get free 10 test-EMC for free on the online faucet on the site: http://emercoin.com/en/for-developers#

Comment: ohk, let me do some more research on it.
Thank you so much for you valuable response !!!